Unable to convert text into dataframe in python
I am trying to convert a text into a dataframe using Python.
sample_text: 'This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34'
Final Desired output:

Steps I am following to achieve the above output are listed below :

Break the text into multiple rows and assign it to a variable: I have tried using print() to process this text formatted_text = print('This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34') but it cant be assigned as print() returns NoneType, so I get an error here.

Desired output after this step:
This is 
sample text

Name|age
--|--
1.abc|45
2.xyz|34


Use the above line break text stored in a variable to be read as a CSV with the separator | to create a dataframe: I have been thinking of processing this as pd.read_csv(formatted_text,sep='|', skipinitialspace=True)

Desired_output after this step:

I tried earlier explaining this problem in SO post but I guess I wasn't able to explain it well and it got closed. I Hope I am able to explain my issue this time. It could be a silly task but I have been stuck at this for a long time now and would appreciate any help.

Why is this tagged pdf-parsing?

Splitting by /n and then by | should do the trick: df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('|') for x in 'This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34'.split('\n')]) Maybe I'm not understanding though?

your str does contain the output you want. That is crucial to understand. You can check print('This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34') yourself

@ScottHunter this issue is actually based on marked down file results that was generated after pdf parsing using ai model

Where the input came from isn't relevant to what is being asked, as indicated by your not including it in the question.

Note, the issue here is that pandas doesn't accept strings to parse as csv, you have to wrap i in a io.StringIO

A possible solution:
text = 'This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34'

pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), lineterminator='\n', engine='c', header=None)

Output:
             0
0     This is 
1  sample text
2     Name|age
3        --|--
4     1.abc|45
5     2.xyz|34


To split the columns, we can use str.split after read_csv:
(pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), lineterminator='\n', engine='c', header=None)[0]
 .str.split('|', expand=True))

Output:
             0     1
0     This is   None
1  sample text  None
2         Name   age
3           --    --
4        1.abc    45
5        2.xyz    34


Thanks a alot PaulS. This is all I wanted and didn't know it was this simple. Was stuck at this from long now. Really Really Appreciate your help. It took me 3 SO post to come to this final Solution. Really Appreciate it. Will accept your answer as soon as it let me.

Need to use sep='|'

Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga! Yes, I had overlooked that. However, sep = '|' does not seem to work -- it gives an error. I still need to check it out.

I don't think you can use read_csv here, there is not a consistent number of fields

@mozway yeah, good point, I simply was pointing out that the final intended fields were delimited by a pipe

Thanks, @mozway. True, we can not use read_csv to split columns, but one can split the columns after having used read_csv, as my second solution shows.

You can just split the rows, then the columns and feed this to the DataFrame constructor, optionally fillna with '':
s = 'This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34'
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('|') for x in s.split('\n')]).fillna('')

Alternatively, using a Series and str.split:
df = pd.Series(s.splitlines()).str.split('|', expand=True).fillna('')

Output:
             0    1
0     This is      
1  sample text     
2                  
3         Name  age
4           --   --
5        1.abc   45
6        2.xyz   34


We can split each line by | into a list and create a dataframe from that:
import pandas as pd

text = 'This is \nsample text\n\nName|age\n--|--\n1.abc|45\n2.xyz|34'

array = [line.split('|') if '|' in line else [line, ''] for line in text.splitlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
print(df)

output:
             0    1
0     This is      
1  sample text     
2                  
3         Name  age
4           --   --
5        1.abc   45
6        2.xyz   34

